# Doctrine character set issue

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, doctrine-orm

I'm sure I'm somehow missing something stupid here. I'm setting up a database using doctrine and because I have a lot of legacy data I'm importing data from an external database. The external database has the latin1 charset, so when I access it I call

```
SET CHARACTER SET utf8
```

to make sure I'll receive utf8 characters from this server. Running

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set%'
```

shows me that the client character set is indeed utf8, the server side character sets are still latin1 as they should be. Now going back to my external database, that one's managed by doctrine. Using the same query shows me that all character sets are indeed utf8. When trying to create a new entry one of the values I want to enter is Juliën, the character ë causes an error.

```
    102085 - An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO Person (id, name_last, name_first, name_infix, gender, username, password_salt, password_hash, password_expires, account_disabled) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params [<id>, "<name_first>", "\x4a\x75\x6c\x69\xe3\xab\x6e", "", "<gender>", "<email>", "<long hash>", "<long hash>", null, 1]:

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect string value: '\xE3\xABn' for column 'name_first' at row 1
```

Now other utf8 characters like ð actually do work. Does anyone have any clue?

The actual string value when being retrieved from the database returns true if compared to the string "Juliën" with ===, and even if I discard the data from the other database and just type the string manually into the code file I get the same error.

Thanks for the help :)

Edit: forgot to share, the entire database is set with charset utf8 and the default collation (which was utf8_unicode_ci iirc).

Edit: after further testing I can enter the entire row by querying manually by getting the connection from the currently used entityManager. So the issue seems to be with Doctrine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no issue with Doctrine of MySQL anywhere, but simply a reminder that your shouldn't call strtolower on utf encoded characters...

Answer (score 0):

Could the problem be caused by your SQL insert statement parameters? It appears as though you're inserting <first_name> where the last name would be expected. Is this intentional?

Comment: Apologies, that was a typo when I was censoring out sensitive data ;) The data being inserted is in fact real data and can be changed without affecting the error in any way.